# Deploy to heroku from bitbucket

Tags: heroku, deployment, bitbucket

I want to deploy my app to heroku and here is my pipeline file

```
image: node:6
clone:
  depth: full
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm test
          - git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git HEAD:master
```

I set the HerokuAppkey and herokuappname in enviroment variables, but i've got error

```
+ git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git HEAD:master
remote: !   WARNING:
remote: !   Do not authenticate with username and password using git.
remote: !   Run `heroku login` to update your credentials, then retry the git command.
remote: !   See documentation for details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#http-git-authentication
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://heroku:@git.heroku.com/humolite.git/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Heroku Account Setting then regenerate api key and replace to $HEROKU_API_KEY.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you've set your account's password to $HEROKU_API_KEY. You need to set a valid token instead.

You can use teh [heroku authorizations:create](https://github.com/heroku/cli/blob/master/docs/authorizations.md#heroku-authorizationscreate) command to create a new token locally. Then, configure your CI to have the right value and your deployment should be working.